# Do all kind of unicellular asexual reproductions let mutations happen, resulting in evolution?

Tags: evolution, reproduction, mutations

I know about fission, an unicellular asexual reproduction method, where the mother cell splits into two daughter cells. Does this kind of asexual reproductions let mutations happen, leading to much needed evolutionary process? Is it same for all unicellular asexual reproductions?

Answer (score 1):

It is not essentially asexual reproduction that causes mutations. Mutations can be caused because of errors in DNA replication which can happen during both [mitosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitosis) and [meiosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis).

Mutations can also be caused because of error-prone [DNA repair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_repair) mechanism.

Other than these intrinsic factors there are physical and chemical mutagens that alter the DNA or accelerate the intrinsic mutagenesis mechanisms.

These mechanisms are universally common for all living organisms (*that we know of :P* ), however, their tolerance to mutagens and rates of intrinsic mutagenesis may vary.

Have a look at [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29795/how-does-hiv-mutate-into-other-strains-while-keeping-their-virulent-phenotype/29960#29960) too.

Comment: I don't know whether my choice of word "facilitate" was right. Can mutation happen in fission?

Comment: Mutations occur during the process of DNA replication (as well as at other times). Of course, DNA replication is necessary for fission.

Comment: @Gulshan Cellular fission (or cytokinesis) is preceded by DNA replication. Even during the formation of gametes (sperm and ova) DNA replication happens which is followed by some steps that are not present in the asexual cell division or mitosis. Click on the links in the above answers; you'll find all the relevant background information.

Comment: I can think of two kinds of asexual reproduction- i) each item of the mother cell is copied to daughter cell. ii) only DNA is copied from the mother cell and rest of the items are constructed from new DNA. I think, mutations can happen in both cases. But only in the second case, the mutation will result to a physical change of the new cell, thus making it subject to evolution. Is my idea alright?

Comment: @Gulshan DNA replication is a prerequisite for cell division. Any mutation in the DNA will be inherited and expressed in the progenies. There can be asymmetric distribution of cellular components but DNA is always replicated and each cell receives a copy. Read about cell division; your doubts will be clear.

Comment: Replication will always be there. But would the translation from genes to actual physical attributes happen in all the cases? As, all other components are directly being copied from mother cell.

Comment: @Gulshan Other components are dependent on the DNA; there is a constant turnover and the stock inherited from the maternal cytoplasm will not last long. Please go through the basics before arguing on a hypothesis. Not all mutations are translated to phenotypic effects. It would take much more than a comment to explain why.

Comment: Actually I do not know these things. I just wanted to be sure about my assumption.